# Apache на Linux. Как открыть порт

Tags: linux, apache

Есть сервер, на котором развернут веб-сервер **Apache**. В списке занятых портов видно, что **Apache** занимает **80-ый порт**, при попытке подключиться к порту, пишет ошибку **connection refused**.
При этом пытаемся выполнить проверку работы локально делаем с помощью **curl**. При попытке добавить порт в **iptables**, ничего не происходит. Подскажите какие логи смотреть и как выйти из данного положения, чтобы сайт заработал хотя бы локально?

Comment: `systemctl status apache2` или типа того должен показать логи.